# Гсч на python с использованием процессора intel 12th gen

Tags: python, случайные-числа, intel

Прочитал, что в современных процессорах есть гсч. Нашел, как использовать этот гсч на С++. Но как реализовать это на python?

Comment: Для «максимального рандома» лучше использовать несколько разных источников случайных чисел — а значит лучше просто воспользоваться стандартными средствами операционной системы, она сама во всём разберётся, в том числе заюзает процессорный гсч если он есть

Comment: Что такое "максимальный рандом"?

Comment: Значит отказ от использования псевдослучайных генераторов чисел